# Django doesn't seem to detect my login.html, block problem?

Tags: python, django, authentication, block

I'm creating a web app with django 1.2.4.

I am using contrib.auth.views.login, I have followed every step but it seems I have forgotten something cause I don't see the login form. Here is my folder structure:

```
/templates/
    base.html
    /myapp/
        object_list.html
        ...
    /registration/
        login.html
```

...and here is my login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block mylogin %}
<div class="horizontal">
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="login_box">
            <div class="login_text">{{ form.username.label_tag }}</div><div class="login_input">{{ form.username }}</div>
            <div class="password_text">{{ form.password.label_tag }}</div><div class="password_input">{{ form.password }}</div>
            <input id="button_login" type="submit" value="" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

...and in my base.html I have:

```
<div id="some_div">
{% block mylogin %} {% endblock %}
</div>
```

I have a basestyle.css included in base.html and the other templates inherit correctly too... it seems to be a block problem...

Any solution??
Thnak you

Comment: How are you rendering that template?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, traceback, etc? Posting those might help.

Comment: mmmm... interesting, you are right cause I am trying to put this login form on every page but when I only include a template, for example: return render_to_response('myapp/object_list.html',        {'items': entry_list,},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))  How can I render login.html on every page without creating a new view for login???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting of a block I used the `include` tag in base.html, just like this:

```
{% include "registration/login.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’d prefer not to call default (django provided) template registration/login.html, you can pass the template_name parameter via the extra arguments to the view in your URLconf.

For example, this URLconf line would use myapp/login.html instead:

`(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),`

Reference : [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)

It solves my problem. Hope this works for others.